# Create individual orders for each item in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

I basically need to be able to create multiple orders for every item in the cart but retain the default checkout process.

To the user, it would look like they are checking out with multiple items but in the backend, it would create multiple orders. [I found an article](https://wpquestions.com/Woocommerce_Create_Order_for_Each_Item/7594) which pretty much relates what I need to do.

I would assume I would need to remove the action that is triggered when clicking the pay now button, preventing the order from being created automatically and create the orders manually. I can access the cart information using the following filter, perhaps this would be a starting point?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wp_handle_multiple_orders', 10, 1 );
function wp_handle_multiple_orders( $order ) {
global $woocommerce;
print_r(count(WC()->cart->get_cart()));

// Handle creation of multiple orders

}
```

Or perhaps I hook into the checkout_process:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wp_handle_multiple_orders' ) );
```

I am aware this process isn't ideal and there are many different things to consider but hopefully, there is an alternative way of achieving this. Any links would be appreciated!

Comment: Dividing an order into multiple orders is not a problem in itself, ONLY. If you want to **display the original order as 1 order on the order-received (thank you) page**, then generally the order has already been split into several orders before that action takes place. If you are going to split the order after the order-received page, the order is already fully created and emails from the original order (with all products) have already been sent.. In short, I think you should look for a plugin that can do this, because it will not work with a few lines of code. Unless I'm overlooking something

Comment: @7uc1f3r yeah, it doesn't matter if the order is displayed as one order on the thank you page, as we have a customised thank you page. It's purely for the backend, so that orders can be managed individually. Thanks hopefully I can find a ready made plugin that might have this covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer contains:

- Keep only 1 product in the original order, delete other products from this order.
- Place the removed products (each separately) in a new order.
- Explanation via comment tags added to the code, the code can easily be expanded further if desired

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {   
    // Get order currency
    $order_currency = $order->get_currency();

    // Get order payment method
    $order_payment_gateway = $order->get_payment_method();
    
    // Address
    $order_address = array(
        'first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
        'last_name'  => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
        'email'      => $order->get_billing_email(),
        'phone'      => $order->get_billing_phone(),
        'address_1'  => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
        'address_2'  => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
        'city'       => $order->get_billing_city(),
        'state'      => $order->get_billing_state(),
        'postcode'   => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
        'country'    => $order->get_billing_country()
    );

    // Shipping
    $order_shipping = array(
        'first_name' => $order->get_shipping_first_name(),
        'last_name'  => $order->get_shipping_last_name(),
        'address_1'  => $order->get_shipping_address_1(),
        'address_2'  => $order->get_shipping_address_2(),
        'city'       => $order->get_shipping_city(),
        'state'      => $order->get_shipping_state(),
        'postcode'   => $order->get_shipping_postcode(),
        'country'    => $order->get_shipping_country()
    );
    
    // Counter
    $counter = 1;

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        // From the 2nd product
        if ( $counter >= 2 ) {
            // Get the WC_Product Object
            $product = $item->get_product();
            
            // Get product quantity
            $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();
            
            // Create new order
            $new_order = wc_create_order();
            
            // Add product to new order
            $new_order->add_product( $product, $product_quantity );
            
            // Set addresses
            $new_order->set_address( $order_address, 'billing' );
            $new_order->set_address( $order_shipping, 'shipping' );

            // Set the correct currency and payment gateway
            $new_order->set_currency( $order_currency );
            $new_order->set_payment_method( $order_payment_gateway );

            // Calculate totals
            $new_order->calculate_totals();

            // Set order note with original ID
            $new_order->add_order_note( 'Automated order. Created from the original order ID: ' . $order_id );
            
            // Set correct status
            $new_order->update_status( 'processing' );

            // Delete product from original order
            $order->remove_item( $item_id );
        }
        
        // Counter = counter + 1
        $counter++;
    }
    
    // Re-calculate & save
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3 );
```